# API Gateway - cannot enable CORS for single domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am new to AWS API Gateway.

I am trying to expose an endpoint to a static page I have hosted on S3. 
I am trying to restrict access to the endpoint so that it can only be called by my domain `example.com`

In API Gateway I click `enable CORS` and by `Access-Control-Allow-Origin*` I am entering `'example.com'`

> The endpoint is not restricted to my domain as expected, I can call it from my dev machine locally

I can't see what I'm doing wrong? I have Googled but can't find anything similar....

Comment: Have you checked the response headers in the browser? Can you give some sample requests/responses?

Comment: CORS is not for access control.  CORS is a mechanism for giving browsers *permission* to make cross-origin requests that they would otherwise be unwilling to make because of the browser's security policy.  This behavior is not unexpected.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Can you elaborate in an answer please? The info in `API Gateway` says "Specifies a domain/origin that may access the resource" - I read this to mean I can restrict the origin/domain that can make a request??

Comment: If I create an endpoint at api.example.net with CORS support to allow origin example.com, anybody anywhere can still access my service, but browsers should refuse to allow XHR requests unless the requesting page is from example.com.  CORS protects my *users* against malicious javascript on the evil.example.org web site from accessing my service, because the *browser* blocks it on their behalf when it sees my CORS configuration.  My service allows it but the browser won't let it through.  It's for user protection, not endpoint protection.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for clarifying that. I know this probabaly isn't the right place but can you advise *how* I can provide access control to my service? My service currently exposes a simple API which allows POSTing email addresses which are stored in Dynamo. How do I stop someone with mailicious intent from writing a script which posts huge amounts of data to my database?

Comment: You'll need to actually authenticate the requests. There is no magic bullet for determining whether requests are genuinely "from" a specific site.  One solution: https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/